# Ubuntu 16.04 - How to override fonts?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04, everything went nice and smooth except when I installed Chrome, and logged in to my account to check my watch history on YouTube, then I came across this weird looking font:

[image].

I checked with Inspect Element to see what font it was, turns out it was

```
font: 12px Roboto,arial,sans-serif;
```

Personally, I don't like it, though on Windows I like it.
Inspect Element's font is weird also.

Why are they different?
Can I change it, currently I'm using Open Sans as my main font.

Answer (score 3):

The default fonts you're disatisfied with are those which are set within your browser, and overriding the system fonts may not be the best approach. If you are using Firefox there are font setting preferences, and if using Chromium you will need to install an extension. You can then preview and choose your preferred fonts in a more flexible way. To get the Microsoft default system fonts in Ubuntu, install the package `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` via your preferred method (ie `apt` in a terminal, `synaptic`, or otherwise) to get Arial. As an alternative to Arial, I also recommend the `fonts-texgyre` package, with TeX Gyre Heros as the best free Helvetica alternative (actually a highly developed and extended set of Nimbus, a grotesk which has a history prior to Helvetica).

More specific to your situation, the diagonal stroke thinning on the "S" and "s", as well as the compressed counters and narrowed aperture in "e", and too-low middle stroke of the "E" seems to indicate that you are using the `infinality` package. To my taste, this package is very unsuited to the default tweaks Ubuntu is already applying to the freedesktop font rendering, and much better for most other distros (like Fedora or OpenSUSE). Basically, it's correcting in addition to the corrections that are built into Ubuntu by default, rather than replacing them. I think the Ubuntu defaults are the best font rendering on any desktop operating system, but if you are a long-time Windows user they will look very different (much less strongly aliased). I recommend uninstalling `infinality` if you do have it on an Ubuntu installation, and if you want to try a tweak, use `unity-tweak-tool` to turn font hinting off completely (allowing the renderer to make all the decisions itself).

Some example screen shots of Youtube at different magnifications, in Chromium. Note that changing system hinting preferences in `unity-tweak-tool` (and logging out and back in to restart the session) did not change the rendering of these tiles in-browser.

Roboto (Youtube default, to compare with OP's screenshot):

[image: Roboto - 110%]

Roboto (size decreased as a test of the compositor's aliasing capabilities):
[image: Roboto - 75%]

Arial (as alternative font) this is with hinting turned off completely, RGBA aliasing. The font renders in a very crisp, MS way.

[image: Arial - 110%]
[image: Arial - 75%]

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. I tried installing  `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, seems I already have it. I'm currently installing` fonts-texgyre`, I'll post again after it's done.  Just a question how should I remove `infinality`?

Comment: You only need to remove `infinality` if you have installed it. If you have installed it, you probably did it with a ppa as suggested by this link:
[webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/better-font-rendering-in-linux-with.html)

If you did, the steps to uninstalling are there, mostly with a `$ sudo apt remove fontconfig-infinality` and removing the ppa from your apt sources list.

Comment: I tinkered a bit with YouTube's CSS, turns out just Roboto looks weird. How can I fix it?

Comment: To me, on that screen shot example, the sans-serif font on the youtube page doesn't look anything like Roboto (the bowl and spur on the "a", etc). I also can't reproduce the really wierd rendering of the "s", "e", "E" etc no matter what I do. I'm using Chromium, and have `hinting: off` in the `unity-tweak-tool`. Is Roboto installed on  your system as well? There's a `fonts-roboto`package in the repos  too.

Comment: My hinting is full, and antialiasing is Greyscale.

Comment: I just installed `fonts-roboto`, it's still the same. Either way, I found the problem, it's the Roboto font that looks weird on Ubuntu, so my fix was this, I installed a font extension on Chrome and changed it for YouTube to use Arial.

Comment: Ah, full hinting would certainly not help, particularly if you turn off sub-pixel aliasing (greyscale vs rgba). Hinting is not necessarily a "more is better" parameter, what it does is to rely on the built-in aliasing guidelines that the font has in it. This was important years ago, and is now only relevant in limited contexts; inside full-color, modern desktop environments (particularly Ubuntu Unity/GNOME), even on `slight` the hinting tables can sometimes mess with stem heights in lining numbers, for example, with heights that will be too tall or short by a pixel depending on their shape.

Comment: Updated answer with screenshots to provide example of default Ubuntu font rendering, with both Roboto and Arial.

Comment: Currently I'm using my Windows machine and I can't switch to Ubuntu, so I'll try it tomorrow, but I tried what you said, I installed Arial, RGBA antialiasing, hinting set to off (though I kinda like it on full), my only dislike is that letters using both Roboto and Arial are slender and condensed, I have been using Windows since Windows 98 came out so I'm kinda used to those letters.

Comment: It's good to confirm that having your system the way you want it is what is best, particularly with regard to appearance. I can only make suggestions based on what I feel are the best comprimises. Have your system the way it makes you most comfortable.

Comment: Yeah, with some tweaks it looks great, but honestly I might be falling in love with Linux, or perhaps with Ubuntu, it's fast, looks great especially with Open Sans and it's open source, and since I'm a software developer that's really nice. Could you perhaps share some Linux sites to get more used to Linux, I like the idea of using the terminal. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Resources for getting comfortable in the terminal number as the stars. If you're using Unity, remembering the shortcut `<Ctrl> + <Alt> + t` to start a new window, and the `<Ctrl> + <Alt> + <numpad direction>` for window snapping makes using it convenient rather than an extra burden.

Answer (score 0):

13.04 and later
For Unity interface users, customisation of fonts can be done using unity-tweak-tool Install unity-tweak-tool
try this and let me know..

Comment: Tried it already, didn't change much.